My Google Pixel 7 shut off on its own and won't turn back on. I've tried to hard reset and still nothing. Is there a way to get it to turn back on?
It is a Google Pixel 7 and is not even a year old. It has never been in water but it's dropped at least 10 times a day. It always had a case and screen protector.
I was in the middle of sending a text and the screen went black and it won't turn back on.
I tried to hard reset it and it still does nothing. I've tried with and without it being on the charger The battery was at 80% when it shut off.

Do you have any reaction (vibrating) if you try to power on the phone?

It'd be better to use tag google-pixel-7, see https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-pixel.

Even if it has a hard case to protect it, if its being dropped 10 times a day then insides are still experiencing G-forces.
The chances are that some internal connectors have come loose.  A common fault is the connector to the screen coming loose or falling off.  You may be able to find YouTube videos showing you how to fix it.  Otherwise take it to a repair shop.
